# YAML: How can I create a multi-line string of comma delimited values?

Tags: string, parsing, yaml, newrelic

I am using YAML to pass in a string of comma delimited values for a new relic config file to ignore errors. I need the output to look like this:

```
"NotFoundError,LocationError,InvalidParamsError"
```

I tried using folded style and stripping the last newline. My yaml file looks like this:

```
ignore_errors: >-
  NotFoundError,
  LocationError,
  InvalidParamsError
```

However, it parses the other newlines as a space in the end giving me something like this:

```
"NotFoundError, LocationError, InvalidParamsError"
```

I need it to parse the folded string and not add spaces. Please help.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

The only way to do this is to quote your string and escape the end of each line with `\`:

```yaml
ignore_errors: "\
  NotFoundError,\
  LocationError,\
  InvalidParamsError"
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the YAML spec will enable you to do what you want, unfortunately ([this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/567863) shows the myriad of ways to write multi-line strings in YAML... but doesn't cover your use case).  I think your best bet if possible would be to store your error strings as a list, and then use your programming language to format the list.  An example in Ruby would be:

```
require 'yaml'

yaml = <<-YAML
  ignore_errors:
    - NotFoundError
    - LocationError
    - InvalidParamsError
YAML
hash = YAML.load(yaml)
puts hash["ignore_errors"].join(',')
```

which gives you `"NotFoundError,LocationError,InvalidParamsError"`